# Unable to go programmatically from a Controller to a View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I would like to perform an action within the viewDidLoad function of my first ViewController which, when a certain value of a var `a` occurs then it goes directly to another ViewController (part of my Storyboard).

Actually, I already implemented something but that's not working:

```
if let curUser = loadAppUser() {
            appUser = curUser
            testLabel.text = "Chargement de l'utilisateur"
            let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let homePageViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homePageViewController") as! HomePageViewController
            self.present(homePageViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            testLabel.text = "Sauvegarde du nouvel utilisateur"
            saveAppUser()
        }
```

Comment: are you sure that you added "homePageViewController" to the identity Storyboard ID ?

Comment: You can't present a view controller from `viewDidLoad` before the presenting view controller has even been created.

Comment: Braham : yes I did.

Comment: Nard : Ok so I should use viewDidAppear instead to put my code?

Comment: Sorry Nard, I add a point, I don't want my view to be loaded and displayed if I have a certain variable already existing. So maybe viewDidAppear would not fit my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to display what I want, by looking through some many posts and website that my eyes are bleeding.

First of all, what I think is an important detail, is that the viewController I want to display is in a NavigationController, but that just asks to add one more line to the solution we could have found to my initial problem.

In my storyBoard, the entry point is set to the application that owns the code below (my OnboardingPage).

So here is the solution:

```
if let curUser = loadAppUser() {
            os_log("User found, loading...", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            appUser = curUser
            let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let homePageVC: UIViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homePageViewController") as UIViewController
            let navHomePageVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homePageVC)
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = navHomePageVC
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        } else {
            os_log("No user found, creating a new one...", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            saveAppUser()
        }
```

And this is working fine.

For people reading this, I found the solution by looking for a different way of executing my needs. In fact this solution works, but I took a totaly different corner, playing with the Appdelegate and a first time launch function (found [here](https://medium.com/anysuggestion/detecting-the-first-launch-of-the-ios-application-the-wrong-and-the-right-way-78b0605bd8b2)).
I'm just checking and saving at applaunch if it's the first launch, then I change the rootViewController of my app, to display the onboarding screens only at first launch.

In this solution, the entry point is set to the homePage (displayed after the OnBoardingPage) so different than in the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

*It seems I go a step further now, but when I come to my next ViewController, then my IBOutlet variables are detected as "nil" (inside the viewDidLoad() function).*

**Replace**

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView : UITableView!
```

**With**

```
@IBOutlet var tableView : UITableView!
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Hi, I didn't have TableView variable in my next controller. I tried based on the same idea to remove weak from my variables, but it does not work either. I guess that you probably thought about variables in my calling Controller to keep the reference, but also there I don't have any TableView.

Comment: @Alexandre tableView was just an example. just remove weak from the variables that you get nil.

Comment: That's what I said, I then did to my own variables but it's not working.